# Remove duplicate node set based on element tag is empty

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, bpel

```
***This is my input xml coming from source.***

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<exampleElement xmlns="http://www.example.org">
<element1>
  <Id>123</Id>
  <Name>Imag</Name>
  <Status>active</Status>
  <EndDate/>
</element1>
<element1>
  <Id>888</Id>
  <Name>Preci</Name>
  <Status>active</Status>
  <EndDate/>
</element1>    
<element1>
  <Id>123</Id>
  <Name>Imag</Name>
  <Status>terminated</Status>
  <EndDate>2016-12-10</EndDate>
</element1>
<element1>
<Id>143</Id>
<Name>kilok</Name>
<Status>terminated</Status>
<EndDate>2016-11-10</EndDate>
</element1>
</exampleElement>
```

In above input data two sets duplicated with different value.Where ID=123 element node has two records with EndDate value and with out EndDate.

```
**I want out put in this below format where one record set 
from duplicates with EndDate tag empty.**

<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns1:exampleElement xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">
<ns1:element1>
  <ns1:Id>888</ns1:Id>
  <ns1:Name>Preci</ns1:Name>
  <ns1:Status>active</ns1:Status>
  <ns1:EndDate/>
</ns1:element1>
<ns1:element1>
  <ns1:Id>123</ns1:Id>
  <ns1:Name>Imag</ns1:Name>
  <ns1:Status>active</ns1:Status>
  <ns1:EndDate/>
</ns1:element1>
<ns1:element1>
  <ns1:Id>143</ns1:Id>
  <ns1:Name>Kilok</ns1:Name>
  <ns1:Status>terminated</ns1:Status>
  <ns1:EndDate>2016-11-10</ns1:EndDate>
  </ns1:element1>
</ns1:exampleElement>
```

Please find the below my xslt where this will give unique records,but I want to get the unique record based on value.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<ns1:exampleElement>
  <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:exampleElement/ns1:element1[not(ns1:Id=following::ns1:Id)]">
    <ns1:element1>
      <ns1:Id>
        <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:Id"/>
      </ns1:Id>
      <ns1:Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:Name"/>
      </ns1:Name>
      <ns1:Status>
        <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:Status"/>
      </ns1:Status>
      <ns1:EndDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:EndDate"/>
      </ns1:EndDate>
    </ns1:element1>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ns1:exampleElement>
```

because from the source system will receive the user Active record in first set and terminated record in second set but we need to forward only active record to target system.Please help on this.

Comment: What is `<EndDate>2016-12-10</terminated>` supposed to be? That is not well-formed XML. As for identifying duplicates in XSLT 1.0, see http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml.

Comment: So what is the criteria to select or eliminate a duplicate element1, the `active` status or the empty `EndDate`?

Comment: Hi Martin,thanks for looking into this query. It's typo mistake and modified the tag name.

Comment: Criteria to select empty  `EndDate`

Comment: Why is the order in the wanted output `888` followed by `123` although in the input the `123` with an empty `EndDate` is the first element? Do you want to reorder the elements?

Comment: Hi Martin,I don't have concern about the out put order,bur source input will recive first EndDate empty record and second or third set will receive the EndDate value record for that same user. We need to send that user EndDate empty record to the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were given a link to an article to Muenchian Grouping in comments, which explains the approach to take. It involves first define a key to match the elements you want to group (where `ns1` is a namespace prefix bound to the namespace URI)

```
<xsl:key name="elements" match="ns1:element1" use="ns1:Id" />
```

Then, to get the distinct ones (or rather, the first occurrence of elements for each possible value of `Id`), you would do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns1:element1[generate-id() = generate-id(key('elements', ns1:Id)[1])]" />
```

And to access all the elements in the group, do this..

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('elements', ns1:Id)">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">  
   <xsl:key name="elements" match="ns1:element1" use="ns1:Id" /> 

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="*/ns1:element1[generate-id() = generate-id(key('elements', ns1:Id)[1])]">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('elements', ns1:Id)">
                    <xsl:sort select="ns1:EndDate" />
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you really wanted to output the XML with `ns1:` prefix (although it really shouldn't make a difference), try this instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">  
   <xsl:key name="elements" match="ns1:element1" use="ns1:Id" /> 

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns1:exampleElement>
            <xsl:for-each select="*/ns1:element1[generate-id() = generate-id(key('elements', ns1:Id)[1])]">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('elements', ns1:Id)">
                    <xsl:sort select="ns1:EndDate" />
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns1:exampleElement>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" priority="2">
        <xsl:element name="ns1:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim,thanks for the update on my query. But i am little bit confuse the above code you provided where to incorporate in my xslt code. I am beginer in XSLT. Hope you  understand ...

Comment: I have provided a complete stylesheet, so it replaces your existing XSLT.

Comment: Hi Tim,tried with your xslt it's giving duplicate records. I want to eliminate the duplicate record where `EndDate` tag has value.Assume 2 records received with the same `Id` but one record has EndDate value another record doesn't have the EndDate value in this case I want to pass only one record that `EndDaye` is empty.

Comment: I've updated my answer so the one with a blank end date is selected.